# Column name from database being changed for no reason. "Invalid Column Name Error"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is the most irritating problem I have ever seen.

I have a Cars table with 5 different column. Also, a Department table.
This is my class:

```
[Table("Cars")]
public class Cars
{
    [Key] public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Department_id { get; set; }
    public string Manufactor { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Department")]
public class Department
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Cars> CarList { get; set; }
}

public class CarsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cars> CarSets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> DepartmentSets { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
    public class CarsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Cars/

        public ActionResult index(int? id)
        {
            CarsContext _CarsContext = new CarsContext();
            List<Cars> C = _CarsContext.CarSets.Where(Car => Car.Department_id == id).ToList();

            return View(C);
        }
}
```

My Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<ASPDemo1.Models.Cars>

@using ASPDemo1.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All Available Cars";
}
<div style="font-family:Arial">
<h2>All Available Cars</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var C in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(C.Name + " - " + C.Year, "Details", new { id = C.ID })
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

For who knows what reason, I get an inner exception from this. This works perfectly when I remove the Department_id code from my class. However, if I define a Department_id, it throws an inner exception stating "Invalid Column Name "Department_id1"". I don't know why, but it's adding 1 to a column name so of course it's gonna be invalid. Is this a bug in visual studio?

Comment: It looks like you're using Entity Framework.  I seriously doubt you've found a bug in Visual Studio - most likely the column name `Department_id` is being interpreted somehow as a key by EF or some other such similar reason.

Comment: I had Department_id as a foreign key but since it was giving an error, i deleted the fk. The error still remains.

Comment: When you had a foreign key defined, was it the same error?

Comment: Yes, same error. This is getting ridiculously stupid... Now that I renamed the id Department_fid on both the source and database, it is giving me the same exception with "Invalid Column name Department_id". Why the heck is it changing the column name every single time...

Comment: This problem is fixed when I remove the code: public DbSet<Department> DepartmentSets { get; set; }, does anyone know why this code causes the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove public List CarList { get; set; } from Department. I dont know why that fixed the problem but it did.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
[Column("ColumnNameInDB", TypeName="int")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: "Name is not a valid named attribute argument"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would prefer doing this,
but in Entity Framework, while referring to a table in database, the c# code pluralizes the table name.
So try renaming your table to Departments... (similarly Frequencies for frequency..etc)
This way even though your table name in C# code is department, it will refer to correct table Departments and thus its columns.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@JohnC1, You mentioned that you removed the "List CarList" and it worked, the reason is likely due to a reference to another DB table and column name. By removing that line you are no longer automatically accessing data linked by foreign key to the Cars table.

If you are using DB first to construct your DB model, it is likely that you have (or had) a duplicate Foreign key or something similar in the database. I received the same error after adding another table (database first) and somewhere duplicated or corrupted a foreign key. Removing the key and reconstructing the .EDMX DB model worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error because I made mistake of having unmatched data type between DB and model class.

```
public string DepartmentID { get; set; } != int DepartmentID of table.

It worked when I fixed it.

Below is my example:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Part10MVC.Models
{
    [Table("tblDepartment")]

    public class Department
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}


    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Part10MVC.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int employeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Part10MVC.Models
{

    public class EmployeeContext: DbContext
    {
      public  DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Part10MVC.Models;

namespace Part10MVC.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Department/

        public ActionResult showDepartment()
        {
            EmployeeContext ec = new EmployeeContext();
            List<Department> departments =ec.Departments.ToList();
            return View(departments);
        }

    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Part10MVC.Models;

namespace Part10MVC.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult showEmployees(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext ec = new EmployeeContext();
            List<Employee> liEmp = ec.Employees.Where(x=>x.DepartmentID==id).ToList();
            return View(liEmp);
        }

    }
}
```